# Displaying XML Hashes in Rails Views Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, hash

I have narrowed down a 33,364 entry XML file to the 1,068 that I need.  Now I am attempting to gather pieces of information from each  node that I have narrowed my search down to, and store each piece of information in a hash, so that I can list out the relevant data in a rails view.

Here is the code in my controller (home_controller.rb) --

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

# REQUIRE LIBRARIES
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def search

end

def listing

    @properties = {}

    # OPEN THE XML FILE
    mits_feed = File.open("app/assets/xml/mits.xml")

    # OUTPUT THE XML DOCUMENT
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(mits_feed)

    doc.xpath("//Property/PropertyID/Identification[@OrganizationName='northsteppe']").each do |property|

        # GATHER PROPERTY INFORMATION
        information = {
            "street_address" => property.xpath("Address/AddressLine1").text,
            "city" => property.xpath("Address/City").text,
            "zipcode" => property.xpath("Address/PostalCode").text,
            "short_description" => property.xpath("Information/ShortDescription").text,
            "long_description" => property.xpath("Information/LongDescription").text,
            "rent" => property.xpath("Information/Rents/StandardRent").text,
            "application_fee" => property.xpath("Fee/ApplicationFee").text,
            "bedrooms" => property.xpath("Floorplan/Room[@RoomType='Bedroom']/Count").text,
            "bathrooms" => property.xpath("Floorplan/Room[@RoomType='Bathroom']/Count").text,
            "bathrooms" => property.xpath("ILS_Unit/Availability/VacancyClass").text
        }

        # MERGE NEW PROPERTY INFORMATION TO THE EXISTING HASH
        @properties.merge(information)
    end

end

end
```

I'm not getting any errors and my view is loading fine, but it is pulling up blank.  Here is my view file (listing.html.erb) --

```
<div class="propertiesHolder">
<% if @properties %>
    <ul>
        <% @properties.each do |property| %>
            <li><%= property.information.street_address %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% else %>
    <h1>There are no properties that match your search</h1>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why this might be pulling up blank?  I would assume that I would receive an error if I had done something incorrect in the code.  I also tried just outputting "Hello World" as text for each |property| and this also pulled up blank.  Thank you!

Comment: if you inspect your `@properties` var in your controller, do you have the information you expect?

Comment: No sir, Justin.  It just pulling an empty hash, output => "{}"

Comment: When I create an empty array [] and add a piece of data to the array via "<<" , it outputs the "Hello World," but I do not know how to store or output my gathered data from that point (when using an array - not that I even feel like this is a positive idea)

Comment: The hash getting to the view is empty, and you should not be putting that much logic in your controller also the information hash has keys that have duplicate names, seems you would confuse yourself with that

Comment: @bjhaid - would you suggest pulling this data and storing it in a DB and then making normal calls to the data that way?

Comment: @NoahNathaniel-DanielDavis, the Controller is not supposed to be concerned with parsing XML and the likes, it's primary responsibility is receiving request(s) and returning the correct response, so you should stick all those logic in a model or some other class, and let that class bother about parsing XML

Comment: @bjhaid - I totally agree, I was just trying to get something up and running quickly to find out where my errors were.  I am still unable to properly grab the data I want via xpath + nokogiri.  I can grab it using the at_css selectors, but these see, to take ages longer to load than the at_xpath selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby `merge` does not mutate your hash. It just returns the two hashes as one.

### Example

```
h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
h1.merge(h2)
#=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>254, "c"=>300}
h1
#=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
```

Note how `h1` still retains its original values?

What you will want to do is rename your `information` hash to `@properties`. I suggest this because you are merging a hash with information in it (`information`) with an empty hash (`@properties`). So instead of overwriting when you merge the hashes, just use the first hash.

Comment: so this returned {"street_address"=>"", "city"=>"", "zipcode"=>"", "short_description"=>"", "long_description"=>"", "rent"=>"", "application_fee"=>"", "bedrooms"=>"", "bathrooms"=>""}, meaning I am obviously not grabbing the text values correctly for each xpath, in addition, how do I store each instance of property to be used in my view? his is only returning one instance.

Comment: I do not understand your question. You are grabbing only one set of properties when you read the XML data.

Comment: I would like to be able to traverse through this set of properties (1,068 of them) to display the data for each individual property in a list on my listing.html.erb page